# Compile error but js get generated

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

This is a new computer setup. All code compile and run on my old comupter.

I have 2 project in my solution than use typescript.
The first compile without problem. 
The second one show error on compile but generate js on save.
I have installed vs 2013 update 5 then installed typescript 1.8.5.
I alsow have vs2015 installed.
After vs2015 was installed i have repair the typescript sdk.

They must have 2 different compiler setup and one in my project is not set correctly.
I have dig into the csproj and compare the 2 project but did not find missing/different parameter for typescript ....

It's like it dont take the new version. I get syntax errors in code i know it compile.

if someone had this problem, please help me.

p.s excuse me for my bad english, im french ...

**UPDATE: Exemple of code dont compile**

```
public doSomething(errorCallBack?: (failCallback1?: JQueryPromiseCallback<any> | JQueryPromiseCallback<any>[], ...failCallbacksN: Array<JQueryPromiseCallback<any> | JQueryPromiseCallback<any>[]>) => void)
{}
```

**Error :**

```
Error   218 Build: ',' expected.
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: no specific error. it's just like it take an old version. Some syntax error in file i know compile ... i have edited my question

Comment: Do you see the error in the editor as well when writing code, or is it only in the compiler output?

Comment: it's only when i build the project. When i save, the js file get updated

Comment: Could you include the error message in the question as well?

Comment: exact same code compile on other computer. i dont wish to modify the code over 20 000 lines of code

Comment: Just a thought...have you tried vscode?  It keeps more up-to-date with the latest TS changes and running tsc -w in the background works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found than visual studio IDE was using 1.8.9 and the compiler was 1.0. This is why i had such compilation errors.

when i used "tsc -v" command in vs2013 command prompt, it show 1.0.
when i use "where tsc" it show only directory for 1.0 and not the 1.8.9.

so, i have replaced the 1.0 content with 1.8.9 . I dont use 1.0.
Now i have a 1.0 directory wish have 1.8.9 in it.

I think this is not the way it's supposed to be, but i need it to work.

It have a .target file i can modify, but i dont wish to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A reduced sample code that fails to compile:

```
class Foo {
    public doSomething(errorCallBack?: (failCallback1?: any, ...failCallbacksN: Array<any>[]>) => void)
    { }
}
```

You have major syntax errors in `...failCallbacksN: Array<any>[]>`. You need something like `...failCallbacksN: Array<any>` e.g.:

```
class Foo {
    public doSomething(errorCallBack?: (failCallback1?: any, ...failCallbacksN: Array<any>) => void)
    { }
}
```

> but js get generated

This is by design. Valid JavaScript will always generate valid TypeScript (even in the presence of errors). The *types* are considered invisible to the emitter in TypeScript so even in the presence of type errors TypeScript will try and do graceful recovery and generate JavaScript.

## More

See Why TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html